# Is it possible to call one function after finishing another without using AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

I've got two functions.

First one, `getLocation()`, gets current location of the device. After getting longitude and latitude I always print them in log, and they are always valid values.

Second function is `findCity()`, and is called right after the first one. It uses coords found from the previous function.

The problem is, second function works like 1/20 times if I try to use coords that i get from the first function. I've found out that coordinates are not always found before second function starts working.

How is it possible to call the second function only after successful finish of the first one?

Comment: You should provide a [mre]

Comment: What does `AsyncTask` have to do with function calling ? You need to call second function only after first is finished . Add [mcve] with question .

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
class getLonLot : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, Void?>() {
        override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
            callYourGetCityMethod()
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
            //Code of Lat Long
            return null
        }
    }
```